# Does DBMS_ALERT work correctly on an oracle RAC cluster?

Tags: oracle

Can anyone confirm whether the oracle DBMS_ALERT package works correctly in a RAC envirnoment.

That is, if I have a DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE() on all instances, then I do a DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL(), will all nodes be signalled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Oh, you wanted more detail than that?

See this blog post, complete w/ test case:
http://vitspinka.blogspot.com/2008/04/dbmsalert-on-rac.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I've seen that post, but I've also seen many other posts, including a paragraph from "Pro Oracle Database 10g RAC on Linux" that say it doesn't.  In fact, every time I see someone say it doesn't work, they are referencing that book.  We are in the process of setting up a RAC test environment on linux VMs but this is progressing slowly.  The only thing I can say confidently is that I can't find anything in oracle's documentation that says it doesn't work.